# A website generator in the browser fetching only the content sources

Tags: cms, static-site-generator

Virtually all websites are made of webservers serving html, either statically or dynamically created from various sources.

Both options need to create the html from the site sources by some somewhat expensive server, either at build time or at request time.

I've been musing about a third option and would like to know if there are some projects tackling this already.

- The files served to visitor browsers are only the site sources, such as markdown, xml/json
  and other assets.
- The html is build dynamically on visiting the site and only the required static assets
  are loaded.
- The editing of content by the site's editors is tackled separately. One option is that
  they simply edit the site sources on something like GitHub.
- Since the only real necessity for serving complete html is SEO, a server version of the
  software does exist, but it's optional, runs infrequently for economic reasons and its
  static html results are served only to crawlers so that proper visitors don't see stale
  content. The infrequent run is fine since crawlers also come only infrequently

The advantage is that hosting becomes cheaper and simpler, as there are no required dynamic server components for the site itself. Only the editing side of things needs some non-static servers, but for that there are cloud solutions like GitHub and those don't lock you in, don't advertise on your site and are cheap.

I was thinking about this while watching a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qcfuA_UAz3I) about the [Fandom](https://www.fandom.com) sites and their struggle with the company hosting them. They initially go there because hosting a Mediawiki wiki is comparatively complicated and expensive.

Comment: My first reaction to reading this is that, if your server CPU time is so expensive that you can't render your website, you should either look for another cheaper hosting or improve your server-side code to use less resources, whenever possible. Fine tunning cache settings may also help. All that before looking for a tool here.